# Javascript Task( a client browser tracking another)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a strange task at work today and I am not asking anyone to solve it for me, just looking forward for some suggestions or advice, so please read attentively.

The Code Should be Purely JavaScript/Jquery Client Side, no Server-side and don't ask me why I am just surprised like you.

We have Two Browsers lets call them A and B, where A has a form (Name, Age, Last Name), when A is triggering any event KeyPress, click, blur, the changes should be reflected to the Browser B, you can compare it to a mirror or a tracking a device that will be seeing what you are clicking, typing etc..

What I tried to do in the beginning is using Ajax, and updating form values of A in Json  type to the server and writing them to file, and then for retrieving the values for Browser B I used the same process with Ajax that will be reading the values from the file. Unfortunately he refused and asked it to be purely client side . eh?

```
 _______________A____________              _________________B______________
|                            |             |                              |
| Name: John                 |             | Name: John                   |
| Last Name: Smi             |  ====>      | Last Name: Smi               |
| Age:                       |             | Age:                         |
|____________________________|             |______________________________|
```

I am Stuck like a cat on the tree any help please ?

Comment: "eh" indeed. Maybe start looking for a better job >_<. This can't be done (with good reason!) as you are well aware.

Comment: Anyone who has tried to connect to a friend's computer to play Doom together knows how hard it is to even find them, never mind communicate with them...

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get that is somewhat production-capable:

- [Meteor sort of fits the bill](https://www.meteor.com/), but it strongly uses a server.

Some experimental stuff:

- The newer [P2P feature of WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/Peer-to-peer_communications_with_WebRTC).
- [Chrome supports TCP/UDP](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/chrome-tcp-udp) in the Canary builds.

I suppose browser extensions should also fit into this requirement, assuming that the browser's extension API supports some sort of networking capability. AFAIK, Chrome and Firefox extensions are written in JS.